# Html.BeginForm() with GET method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms

How can I specify that my form should be using GET method with @Html.BeginForm() ?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(method: FormMethod.Get))
```

Here VS complains that best overload doesn't have a parameter method. Thank you!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460344.aspx) that allows you to specify the method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("someAction", "someController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you don't know the action and route just place null,null,FormMethod.Get .

Answer (score 2):

Decorate the controller's action method with [HttpGet]. This is the controller action that this form will submit to.