# MVC C# - call GET Create instead of POST Create in button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

In my RequestController I have 2 methods with the same name, Create(), 1 for GET and 1 for POST.
I want to call the GET method in a button.
It works as text like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
```

But in a button it calls the POST Create method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Request"))
{
    <button type="submit">New Request</button>
}
```

RequestController methods:

```
    //
    // GET: /Request/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Expenses, "ID", "Department");

        var destinations = from t in db.Typevalues
                           where t.Typeschema.SchemaCode == "CTY"
                           select t;

        ViewBag.Destinations = destinations;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Request/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Request request)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Requests.Add(request);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Expenses, "ID", "Department", request.ID);
        return View(request);
    }
```

How do I call the GET method in the button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html.BeginForm() with GET method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533894/html-beginform-with-get-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your template specify the form method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Request", FormMethod.Get)) {
    <button type="submit">New Request</button>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What others have said should indeed work, however, I'd encourage you to think about what you're really trying to do. Based upon your code, it seems to me using a regular link (which can easily be styled as a button) would make more sense semantically.

If it's not *really* a form with data that needs to be submitted, in my opinion, it doesn't belong in a form.

Answer (score 3):

You should replace your submit button with a plain HTML link:

```
<a class="button" href="@Url.Action("Create", "Request")">New Request</a>
```

and add a "button" class to you styles to simulate a button. 
Or if you want to keep the button:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="top.location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Request")'; return false;">New Request</button>
```

Comment: I might use this later.
But here again, how do I call the GET Create method?

Comment: You can call the GET Create method by navigating (not via a post) to the /Request/Create URL. The submit button will POST or GET to the form action depending on the form method. So the only way to make a submit button to call a GET method is to change the form method to GET (see answer below for this)

Answer (score 1):

In every HTML form you should specify form method, otherwise it defaults. In your case one form (POST) goes:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Request", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <button type="submit">New Request</button>
}
```

And the other one (GET):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Request", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <button type="submit">New Request</button>
}
```

Or the same what you had, which default to GET:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Request"))
{
    <button type="submit">New Request</button>
}
```